# dig and host/ping resolve differently using the same nameserver

Tags: linux, dns, cache

I guess this is more of a philosophical question.

Records have changed, but only `dig` seems to see the new one. `ssh`/`ping` and such use the old address.

The TTL of the record `dig` sees is also ticking correctly.

Is this really the nameserver responding differently or just a hidden DNS cache?

```
$ host -v boing
Trying "boing"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7276
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;boing.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
boing.      1213    IN      CNAME   ec2-52-209-211-218.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
ec2-52-209-211-218.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 514066 IN A 52.209.211.218

Received 112 bytes from 192.168.0.1#53 in 1 ms
```

whereas:

```
$ dig @192.168.0.1 boing

; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P2 <<>> @192.168.0.1 boing
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34806
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;boing.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
boing.      3441    IN      CNAME   ec2-52-211-117-189.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
ec2-52-211-117-189.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 604641 IN A 52.211.117.189

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Sep 24 12:08:50 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

Comment: What `cat /etc/resolv.conf` does return? It's possible that your OS uses dnsmasq as a DNS caching service.

Comment: @Huygens no dnsmasq, both programs use 192.168.0.1 for DNS

Comment: Sadly it goes behind my expertise then :-( If no one can help you, I can give you a further hint: run `tcpdump` to capture the dns flow for both queries and answers. See if anything in the queries are different, if you have a difference, then you might find out why (via some googling possibly). I would execute this: `sudo tcpdump -w ~/dns.pcap -s 0 -i any udp port 53` This will generate a file dns.pcap in your home directory. You can open it using a tool such as Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I did a test on my CentOS box,the DNS query did correctly reach both a unique name server and both returned the same IP address. However dig set one flag (the AD bit for authenticated data) in the query, whereas host did not set it, and dig set the additional records of type OPT (for DNSSEC AFAIK) but did not set the DO bit, so AFAIK it stated that it can't handle DNSSEC extension. Apart from that both queries where identical.